# Only last week value pine script

Tags: time, pine-script

I am trying to get only last week high/low values,**NOT** all weeks values

```
t = input(title = "study", defval="W", options=["D","W"])
shigh = security(tickerid, t, high[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
slow = security(tickerid, t, low[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
r = shigh-slow
center=(sclose)
h1=sclose + r*(1.1/12)
c5=sopen != sopen[1] ? na : red
plot(h5, title="H5",color=c5, linewidth=2)
```

As you can see in the chart are displayed all weeks since creation...I want only last week!not to show all of them into the chart.

Can someone show me how its done?

Comment: Your script is not compiled, so there is no way to see the chart. Lay out the full script and someone will help you.

Comment: the only thing missing is the title... everything works if u try

Comment: I already tried it, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)

t = input(title = "study", defval="W", options=["D","W"])

[sopen, shigh, slow, sclose] = security(syminfo.tickerid, t, [open[1], high[1],low[1],close[1]], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)

r       = shigh-slow
center  = (sclose)
h5      = sclose + r*(1.1/12)
c5      = sopen != sopen[1] ? na : color.red

plot(h5, title="H5",color=c5, linewidth=2)
```

Update: only show current week.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)

t = input(title = "study", defval="W", options=["D","W"])

thisweek = year(timenow) == year(time) and weekofyear(timenow) == weekofyear(time)

[sopen, shigh, slow, sclose] = security(syminfo.tickerid, t, [open[1], high[1],low[1],close[1]], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)

r       = shigh-slow
center  = (sclose)
h5      = sclose + r*(1.1/12)
c5      = sopen != sopen[1] ? na : color.red

plot(thisweek ? h5 : na, title="H5",color=c5, linewidth=2)
```

Comment: Hi Bjorn ,thank you for your response ,it givesme this error:`variableType.itemType is not a function` on `security(syminfo.tickerid,`.What is the difference with my code?

Comment: My guess is that your script doesn't have the `//@version=4` line, which tells the compiler the Pine version it's supposed to use. This line should always be included in a script.

Comment: yes,after modifying the code for v4 ,I made it work.however even this does not limit the time to only last week,it processes all previous weeks ..just like my code

Comment: Oh, ok. I must've read over that. I've updated my answer to only show the current week. (if that's what you mean by the last week).